# Wait for any of given Futures in Scala?

Tags: multithreading, scala, future

Suppose I need to execute a few parallel tasks in Scala. Each task performs some blocking call (e.g. `Process.waitFor`). Now I would like to wait until any of the tasks completes.

As I understand I should use Scala `Future` to wrap the task. Is there any API in Scala to wait until any of given `Futures` finishes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is build-in method for doing this:

```
Future.firstCompletedOf(yourFutures)
```

[from the doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$):

> Returns a Future to the result of the first future in the list that is
>   completed.

Note that this would not interrupt all other futures so you have cancel them by yourself, if you need to.